# pipe does not exist on type error after applying pipes for rxjs 6 operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am upgrading my angular 4 to angular 6 application.  Which has multiple rxjs operators. I have tried to pipe them but have issues with the braces. Its complaining on the fifth pipe .Could some one tell me what the issue is

```
import { Observable, fromPromise, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap , map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

original

```
confirmRemoveStrategy(): Observable<Action> {
        return this.action$.ofType(CONFIRM_REMOVE_STRATEGY)
            .switchMap((thisAction: ConfirmRemoveStrategyAction) => {
                return Observable.from(this._modalService.confirm(this.buildConfig())).map(confirmed => {
                    return { confirmed: confirmed, action: thisAction };
                });
            })
            .map((result) => {
                return <Action>{
                    type: result.confirmed ? REMOVE_STRATEGY : 'cancel',
                    payload: result.action.payload
                };
            });
    }
```

modified

```
confirmRemoveStrategy(): Observable<Action> {
    return this.action$.pipe(ofType(CONFIRM_REMOVE_STRATEGY))
        .pipe(switchMap(((thisAction: ConfirmRemoveStrategyAction) => {
            return pipe(fromPromise(this._modalService.confirm(this.buildConfig())).pipe(map(confirmed => {
                return { confirmed: confirmed, action: thisAction };
            })));
        })
        .pipe(map((result) => {
            return <Action>{
                type: result.confirmed ? REMOVE_STRATEGY : 'cancel',
                payload: result.action.payload
            };
        }))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `pipe` there. Simply remove it:

```
.pipe(switchMap(((thisAction: ConfirmRemoveStrategyAction) => {
        return from(this._modalService.confirm(this.buildConfig())).pipe(map(confirmed => {
            return { confirmed: confirmed, action: thisAction };
        }));
    })
```

Also, change `fromPromise` to `from`.